# Find strings starting with a string

Tags: regex

How do I search a string say `suffix*` in a text block which has many superstrings containing the string I want to search for eg. `*prefixsuffix*`? I want results which start with `suffix...`

Comment: Can you give examples of what your input/output would look like?

Comment: Whatever you want the results `suffix..` to start with, you have to include that in the regex: I.e. `(?#starts with)suffix\*`

Comment: Are you searching for **words** starting with `suffix`? If not, what then?

Comment: i am trying to find words in my code starting with say 'person%'  but dont want to see results like 'prefixedperson%'

Answer (score 0):

Regex : *(As I got the impression that you want to find words starting from suffix)*

```
suffix\w+
```

**Note:** ***Just replace the suffix with the word you wanted to match against the text starting with***